# std::set elements vanishes away

Tags: c++, stl

I've created a `std::set` in the following code where elements are kept sorted based on an array.

```
int weight[] = {0, 1, 58, 21, 10, 21, 24};

struct Comp
{
    public:
    bool operator() (const int &a, const int &b) const
    {
        if (weight[a] == weight[b])
            return a < b;
        else
            return weight[a] < weight[b];
    }
};
set<int, Comp> s;
```

Surprisingly, when I change any element in the `weight` array, corresponding element in the set vanishes away. Here is my testing function:

```
void print()
{
    printf("Elements = ");  
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        if(s.find(i) != s.end())
            printf("%2d ", i);;
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{   
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        s.insert(i);

    print();
    weight[2] = 1;
    weight[5] = 15;
    print();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Elements =  1  2  3  4  5  6  
Elements =  1  3  4  6
```

I'm using `gcc 4.6.3` in buntu.

Comment: Why is that surprising? `s.find()` uses your `weight` array, so if you change it, you should expect `find` to behave differently.

Comment: You are changing the ordering criteria for the set after it has been constructed. This cannot work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per Paragraph 23.2.4/3 of the C++11 Standard on requirements of associative containers:

> The phrase “equivalence of keys” means the equivalence relation imposed by the comparison and not the
>   `operator==` on keys. That is, two keys `k1` and `k2` are considered to be equivalent if for the comparison
>   object `comp`, `comp(k1, k2) == false && comp(k2, k1) == false`. **For any two keys `k1` and `k2` in the
>   same container, calling `comp(k1, k2)` shall always return the same value**.

Since you are not fulfilling this precondition by changing the weights (and your comparator uses those weights to define an ordering on elements of your set), your program has **Undefined Behavior**.

Answer (score 1):

As a corollary of what Andy Prowl quoted, you would need to regenerate a new set every time you change your weight array